# WPF Can you clear video memory?

Tags: wpf, performance, video-memory

I have a very rich media based application built in WPF, and Im using lots and lots of different PNG images to add animations and materials to 3D objects, as well as 2D animations.

I have noticed that quickly the video memory fills up, and Im looking into trying to clear it.

I don't seem to be able to do anything through C# to force the video memory to get cleared, so Im wondering if a normal GC on objects that reference the graphics (BitmapImage objects) will clear out the Video Memory?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, so what I ended up finding out

(via help here: 
http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/wpf/thread/181da889-31a2-4e4c-b87e-d864577a41d4
)

was that I needed to de-reference my static lists of BitmapImages in order to clear them out of video memory.

I was keeping them around and making the assumption that when no materials were referencing the bitmaps, then the bitmaps would be removed from the video memory.